# Accessing nested values in JSON data from Twitch API

Tags: python, dictionary, twitch

I am using the code:

```
getSource = requests.get("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams")
text = json.loads(getSource.text)
print text["streams"]["_links"]["_self"]
```

text is a dictionary that I get by calling json.loads. I then try to get the nested values, eventually trying to get the url but this error shows up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Twitch Strim.py", line 11, in <module>
    print text["streams"]["_links"]["_self"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: Either `text` or `text["streams"]` or `text["streams"]["_links"]` is `list` type. Check all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing the json data wrong, the correct way of accessing this would be:

```
print text["streams"][0]["_links"]["self"]
```

Full code:

```
>>> import requests
>>> import json
>>> getSource = requests.get("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams")
>>> text = json.loads(getSource.text)
>>> print text["streams"][0]["_links"]["self"]
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/summit1g
>>> print text["streams"][1]["_links"]["self"]
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/tsm_theoddone
>>> print text["streams"][2]["_links"]["self"]
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/reynad27
```

Note that `text["streams"]` provides you a list of items (and not a dict), so you will have to access by its index values.

You can check the same using

```
>>> type(text["streams"])
<type 'list'>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that you have a list at "text" object. I think you should print the variable test to view its content.

Comment: It's showing {u'_total': 14315, u'streams': [{u'_id': 13112245728L, u'created_at': u'2015-02-12T20:08:46Z', u'game': u'Counter-Strike: Global Offensive', u'_links': {u'self': u'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/summit1g'}, u'channel': {u'updated_at': u'2015-02-13T05:16:52Z',...} when I do text["streams"] it shows the key value inside streams but anything after that, I get the error